# Movesense, system time in milliseconds

Tags: movesense

What is the correct way to get a current time in milliseconds at the Movesense platform?

In the simulator env the `ftime` works fine, but it doesn't link
to `dfu` binary (undefined reference to `ftime`):

```
struct time t_start;
ftime(& t_start)
```

I tried out also this one, but I didn't get a proper time:

```
struct timeval te; 
gettimeofday(&te, NULL); // get current time
```

Comment: Did you get the answer to your question in my answer or is it something that is still not clear? If it answers your question please mark it as the accepted answer, if not please clarify what is still missing, and maybe I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you are on an embedded device and not all functions are available to use

gettimeofday() is part of CTIME and is probably not available on the movesense unless you or the Movesense team have implemented it for this platform.

To get the device time use the [time API](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/time.yaml) provided by the Movesense team.

When starting the module

```
whiteboard::ResourceId mTimeResourceId;
getResource("Time",mTimeResourceId); // this returns a status HTTP status code
```

Then when you want the time get it with:

```
asyncGet(mTimeResourceId);
```

Then the response can be gathered in this way.

```
void OverskuddService::onGetResult(whiteboard::RequestId requestID,
                               whiteboard::ResourceId resourceId,
                               whiteboard::Result resultCode,
                               const whiteboard::Value& rResultData)
{
    switch(resourceId.localResourceId)
    {
        case WB_RES::LOCAL::TIME::LID:
        {
          if(resultCode == wb::HTTP_CODE_OK)
          {
             int64_t currentTime = rResultData.convertTo<int64_t>();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the number of uSec since 1970 so covert to ms by dividing by 1000.

Also, be aware that the clock is set to 2015.01.01 if not set when the battery is removed or the chip is put into sleep mode.

Be aware that the timestamps are different for different services, ms from epoch, us from epoch seconds from epoch etc.

**EDIT**: 
As mentioned by *user1987093* (Working for the Movesense team I think) you can also get additional information by doing a GET request to the /Time/Detailed, this gives the current UTC time [us], RelativeTime ie. Timestamp [ms since reset] (same as the Timestamp in sensor services), Resolution [ticks per second] as well as the Accuracy [ppm]

Comment: Good answer Morten. 

Also the _/Time/Detailed_ gives the current UTC time [us], _RelativeTime_ ie. _Timestamp_ [ms since reset] (same as the Timestamp in sensor services), _Resolution_ [ticks per second] as well as the _Accuracy_ [ppm].